# Eclipse project not reading depdencies inside the POM file

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, import, compilation

In Eclipse Neon, I did an 'import existing maven project' from a local folder, whose content was copied from another machine.  The project is not reading the dependencies on the POM file, and one example is the log4j dependency.  A workaround is to add the log4j-1.2.17.jar manually to the project as an external jar, but this is wrong.  Does anyone have tips on how to troubleshoot?  I am fairly inexperienced with maven so I m not sure if there are additional settings or configuration that I have do when importing an existing project into eclipse.

Comment: Are some not downloaded or all? What happens, if you run "mvn compile" from the console, from within the project directory? Are there errors in the "problems" view? Or just post the pom.xml ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can make sure if your project dependencies are being pulled correctly or not by executing

```
mvn clean install
```

from within the project directory on the command line. This would download the required dependencies of the project as well.

Answer (score 0):

The most common cause I have seen for this issue occurs whenever Maven encountered an error while downloading an artifact from a repository. In this case, Maven marks the download as failed and won't retry until some time elapses (I do not remember how long).

The easiest way to test this is to delete the .m2/repository folder in your home directory and let Maven download the artifacts again. If you have Maven installed you just execute "mvn install" from a console. Otherwise, you can try:

1. Right click the project in Eclipse
2. Select "Maven > Update Project"
3. Check "Force Update of Snapshots/Releases"
4. Click "OK"

Comment: Your steps helped me uncover another issue.  I have not one, but multiple projects, lets call them A and B.  A's pow file has a dependency on a jar compiled from B.  I have configured A to have B as a required project during the built process.  But A is not able to pickup this jar file.  So I manually add this jar to A's build path and it seems to clear some of the compile time problems.  However the problem about not able to pickup log4j*.jar is still there and I verify this jar is on one of my local maven download folders.  What else can I try to troubleshoot this problem?

Comment: @kenwood If you see an error in the Problems View that says "Project configuration is not up-to-date with pom.xml" then follow the steps I mentioned to update the project.

Comment: @kenwood You may wish to try deleting the log4j folder from .m2/repository. Maven ties an artifact to the repo where it originally found it. If your configuration changed so that it is attempting to use a different repo, Maven won't use the one you have locally and it won't try to replace it.

Comment: There is no 'project config not up to date with pom.xml' error.  I removed the all 3 versions of log4j from the ./m2 folder and did a maven update.  Eclipse re-downloaded the log4j jar files, but I am still getting compile time error about not able to resolve 'import org.apache.log4j.Logger;', any other suggestions to trouble shoot?